# How to search ID of object nvarchar value on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tableOne`:

```
+------+---------+
|  ID  |  Pages  |
+------+---------+
|  1   |  1,2,3  |
|  2   |  2,3    |
|  3   |  2      |
+------+---------+
```

Now I want to get ID of `tableOne` where my Page exists.

Example query:

```
select * from tableOne where Pages = 3
```

Output should be:

```
+------+---------+
|  ID  |  Pages  |
+------+---------+
|  1   |  1,2,3  |
|  2   |  2,3    |
+------+---------+
```

Comment: Fix your data model so you are not storing numbers in a comma-delimited list.  That is not the right way to store a list in SQL.

Comment: Which RDMS are you using?

Comment: @Luv, I'm using MSSQL Server 2016

Comment: @RichardCalumpang: Go for in-built Function: STRING_SPLIT()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple logic**

```
SELECT * FROM tableone
WHERE Pages LIKE '%,3,%'
      OR Pages LIKE '3,%'
      OR Pages LIKE '%,3'
```

If you are using SQL Server 2016 and above then use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): (Not tested)

```
SELECT Id, Pages
FROM tableOne 
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Pages, ',');  
WHERE value  = '3'
```

Precise Answer:

You have to create SPLIT function to split strings (If you are not using SQL Server 2016 or above)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

And to use it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM tableone 
CROSS APPLY dbo.splitstring(Pages)
WHERE name = '3'
```

Comment: I use this query:
SELECT * FROM tableone WHERE 
Pages LIKE '%,3,%'
OR Pages LIKE '3,%'
OR Pages LIKE '%,3'
OR Pages = 3

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL, you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * FROM tableone WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, Pages);
```

Output:

```
ID  Pages
1   1,2,3
2   2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider changing your stored data, so each page will be stored in one row separately.

If you can't, then you could use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableOne 
WHERE ',' + Pages + ',' LIKE '%,3,%';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using postgres sql

```
 SELECT * FROM (select id, unnest(string_to_array(pages,','))::integer AS ids from tableone) as a  where ids = 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTbl
WHERE Yourcolumn LIKE '%word1%'
```

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM tableone
WHERE Pages LIKE '%3%'
```

Finds any values that have "3" in any position

Comment: This will also get the data that consist Pages 31, 32, 33 and other numbers that contains 3. I need to get specifically data that equals to my Page ID.